# What brand/type of acrylic paints is recommended to paint ceramic pots without leaving brush marks?

Tags: painting, acrylic-paint, ceramics, paint-brushes

Not sure if it's the brushes or the brand of acrylic paints (DecoArt or Martha Stewart Satin Finish) I use, but I'd like to achieve a smooth finish when I paint my ceramic pots.

Comment: Hi Syan, is spraypainting not an option?

Comment: I suspect it isn't so much a matter of brand as consistency.  Very thick paint can act a little like texture medium.  It needs to be thin enough to self-level.  Try thinning the paint.  Also try applying several thin layers using thinned paint rather than one heavy layer using thick paint.

Comment: Hi @Joachim, I wanted to paint some custom art/shapes on the pot. Afraid I won't be able to do such delicate painting by using spray paint.

Comment: @fixer1234: Ahh okay, this might work.. I will try this.

Comment: Syan, can you let us know whether or not it worked? You can answer your question yourself if it did, and, if not, [edit] your question to get more advice.

Comment: Use a paint with dilatent properties ; it will thin and flow after application.

Answer (score 2):

A few options:

- **Watering down the paint** (as mentioned in the comments) Acrylic paint can be thinned by adding water until brush strokes self-level. If you want to be uptight, use distilled water. Chlorine and minerals in tap water may have some effect on the paint, but it's doubtful that it'd be significant.
- **Foam brush** Foam brushes are often used to avoid brush strokes. You used the word "delicate" in your question, so this may not be an option.
- **Spray Painting (with stencils)**. Depending on what your art is, you might be able to create a stencil for it and then spray paint. You can buy removable self-adhesive vinyl from a crafting store (electrical tape works in a pinch) and either cut it manually or find someone with a computer driven cutting machine like a Cricut or Silhouette.